# Converting numbers into full written words

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a script in Linux that converts numbers into full written words. Due to a shortage in time I'll have to settle for a code without the exceptions and numbers after the comma, but it still doesn't work. The program doesn't recognize the variables so I mostly need assistance involving the syntax. This is what I have for now (in Dutch).

Update: I translated the most important (I think) part into English.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -prijs "Give the price: "
read price

thousands='expr $price /1000'
hundreds='expr ($price - $thousands) / 100'
teens='expr ($price - $hundreds - $thousands / 10'
units='expr $price - $hundreds - $thousands - $teens'

    for ((i=0 ; i<=$thousands; i++ ))
do
    case $thousands in
        0) echo -prijs "";;
        1) echo -prijs "duizend";;
        2) echo -prijs "tweeduizend";;
        3) echo -prijs "drieduizend";;
        4) echo -prijs "vierduizend";;
        5) echo -prijs "vijfduizend";;
        6) echo -prijs "zesduizend";;
        7) echo -prijs "zevenduizend";;
        8) echo -prijs "achtduizend";;
        9) echo -prijs "negenduizend";;
        10) echo -prijs "tienduizend";;
    esac
done
    for ((i=0 ; i<=$hundreds; i++ ))
do
    case $hundreds in
        0) echo -prijs "";;
        1) echo -prijs "honderd";;
        2) echo -prijs "tweehonderd";;
        3) echo -prijs "driehonderd";;
        4) echo -prijs "vierhonderd";;
        5) echo -prijs "vijfhonderd";;
        6) echo -prijs "zeshonderd";;
        7) echo -prijs "zevenhonderd";;
        8) echo -prijs "achthonderd";;
        9) echo -prijs "negenhonderd";;
    esac
done
    for ((i=0 ; i<=$teens; i++ ))
do
    case $teens in
        0) echo -prijs "";;
        1) echo -prijs "tien";;
        2) echo -prijs "twintig";;
        3) echo -prijs "dertig";;
        4) echo -prijs "veertig";;
        5) echo -prijs "vijftig";;
        6) echo -prijs "zestig";;
        7) echo -prijs "zeventig";;
        8) echo -prijs "tachtig";;
        9) echo -prijs "negentig";;
    esac
done
    for ((i=0 ; i<=$units; i++ ))
do
    case $units in
        0) echo -prijs "";;
        1) echo -prijs "een";;
        2) echo -prijs "twee";;
        3) echo -prijs "drie";;
        4) echo -prijs "vier";;
        5) echo -prijs "vijf";;
        6) echo -prijs "zes";;
        7) echo -prijs "zeven";;
        8) echo -prijs "acht";;
        9) echo -prijs "negen";;
    esac
done

echo "The price is: " 'expr $thousands + $hundreds + $teens + $units'
```

Comment: Please remove your screenshots and paste your code directly into your question.  Then highlight it and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Keen it looks like you have accidentally created two accounts.  Please visit the help section on [merging accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Why are you adding the (non-existent) options `-prijs` to every `echo` ?  Or do you really intend the string `-prijs` to be inserted between every place value?

Comment: FYI there appears to be a perl module for that: [Lingua::NL::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/~friffin/Lingua-NL-Numbers-1.3/Numbers.pm)

Comment: There's also a [Python module num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) that already supports Dutch.

Comment: Also, you could use arrays instead of those ugly `case` statements: `tho_arr=("" "duizend" "tweeduizend" ...)` and then instead of the `case` just: `echo "${tho_arr[thousands]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. The first issue is that you're using single quotes where you should use backticks. The second issue is that `expr` is not really needed in bash, `$(())` will do the job. The third issue is that the formula is simply wrong. The fourth issue is the `-prijs` as pointed out in the comment. Rewrite this part of your code,

```
thousands='expr $price /1000'
hundreds='expr ($price - $thousands) / 100'
teens='expr ($price - $hundreds - $thousands / 10'
units='expr $price - $hundreds - $thousands - $teens'
```

to

```
thousands=$((price/1000))
hundreds=$((price%1000/100))
teens=$((price%100/10))
units=$((price%10))
```

where `%` is the modulo operator in bash. Try to fix the rest (for example the `-prijs` stuff, and the last line of your script) by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting challenge. Here's my take

```
#!/bin/bash

digits=(
    "" one two three four five six seven eight nine
    ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eightteen nineteen
)
tens=("" "" twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety)
units=("" thousand million billion trillion)

number2words() {
    local -i number=$((10#$1))
    local -i u=0
    local words=()
    local group

    while ((number > 0)); do
        group=$(hundreds2words $((number % 1000)) )
        [[ -n "$group" ]] && group="$group ${units[u]}"

        words=("$group" "${words[@]}")

        ((u++))
        ((number = number / 1000))
    done
    echo "${words[*]}"
}

hundreds2words() {
    local -i num=$((10#$1))
    if ((num < 20)); then
        echo "${digits[num]}"
    elif ((num < 100)); then
        echo "${tens[num / 10]} ${digits[num % 10]}"
    else
        echo "${digits[num / 100]} hundred $("$FUNCNAME" $((num % 100)) )"
    fi
}

with_commas() {
    # sed -r ':a;s/^([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})/\1,\2/;ta' <<<"$1"
    # or, with just bash
    while [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})(.*) ]]; do
        set -- "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    done
    echo "$1"
}

for arg; do
    [[ $arg == *[^0-9]* ]] && result="NaN" || result=$(number2words "$arg")
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$(with_commas "$arg")" "$result"
done
```

In action:

```
$ bash ./num2text.sh 9 98 987 9786 98765 987654 9876543 98765432 987654321 9876543210 98765432100 987654321000 9876543210000 98765432100000 987654321000000 1,234 x 1y z2
9       nine
98      ninety eight
987     nine hundred eighty seven
9,786   nine thousand seven hundred eighty six
98,765  ninety eight thousand seven hundred sixty five
987,654 nine hundred eighty seven thousand six hundred fifty four
9,876,543       nine million eight hundred seventy six thousand five hundred forty three
98,765,432      ninety eight million seven hundred sixty five thousand four hundred thirty two
987,654,321     nine hundred eighty seven million six hundred fifty four thousand three hundred twenty one
9,876,543,210   nine billion eight hundred seventy six million five hundred forty three thousand two hundred ten
98,765,432,100  ninety eight billion seven hundred sixty five million four hundred thirty two thousand one hundred
987,654,321,000 nine hundred eighty seven billion six hundred fifty four million three hundred twenty one thousand
9,876,543,210,000       nine trillion eight hundred seventy six billion five hundred forty three million two hundred ten thousand
98,765,432,100,000      ninety eight trillion seven hundred sixty five billion four hundred thirty two million one hundred  thousand
987,654,321,000,000     nine hundred eighty seven trillion six hundred fifty four billion three hundred twenty one million
1,234   NaN
x       NaN
1y      NaN
z2      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

For future me and people looking for this command.

---

There is this command I stumbled upon scrolling the tab list:

```
spellout 1.0.11: convert numbers to number names and money amounts
Usage: spellout [-l lang] [-p prefix] par1 [par2...]
Parameter: n: number; n-m: range; n-m~s: range with step
Examples: spellout 1-10 500 1000-10000~1000
          spellout -l en-GB -p ordinal 1-100
          spellout -l en -p ordinal-number 1-100
          spellout -l en -p USD 100.45
          spellout -l en -p "money USD" 100.45
Help of language module: spellout -l es help
License: GNU LGPL/BSD dual-license
```

I found out that it (probably) comes from [Numbertext/libnumbertext](https://github.com/Numbertext/libnumbertext) and is available in [Debian sources](https://sources.debian.org/src/libnumbertext/1.0.11-4/src/spellout.cxx/#L13)

---

#### Example:

```bash
$ spellout 39825
thirty-nine thousand eight hundred twenty-five
$ spellout -l de-DE 39825
neununddreißigtausendachthundertfünfundzwanzig
$ spellout -l en-US -p "money GBP" 39825
thirty-nine thousand eight hundred twenty-five pounds sterling
$ spellout  -l de-DE -p ordinal 39825
neununddreißigtausendachthundertfünfundzwanzigste
```