# Any way to interpret string representing an integer or operation?

Tags: linux, shell-script, arithmetic

Lets say I have this string

```
one plus two
```

Is there any way we can interpret this as `1 + 2` faster than going into some conditions checking word per word and testing it if it equal something in a given list? Like

```
if [ `(word)` = "one" ]
elif [ `(word)` = "two" ]
```

etc..

Comment: A broad challenge; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413475/117549 may help.

Comment: Also: https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Words2Nums , if Perl is an option.